# Beginner PHP / SQL / AJAX - Query not working when parameter passed to server side script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

I am beginning to learn PHP + AJAX + SQL. I cannot seem to crack the syntax issue I am running into. I am running the latest WAMP version on a server in my network as the test environment.

I have the following script in my INDEX.PHP (from [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        str = document.getElementById("cn").value;

        if (str=="")
          {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="No name typed, returning all rows ";
          str="all";
          }; 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          };
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          };

        xmlhttp.open("GET","getcustomer.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    });
});
</script>
```

I then have a server side script called GETCUSTOMER.PHP which contains (in part) the following:

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];

echo "The variable contains = ".$q;   **<--- this shows me on the browser the correct variable value is passed to the server side script**

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','phpuser','abc123','learnphp');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  };

mysqli_select_db($con,"PHP_AJAX_Demo");
if ($q == "all") {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM customers";
} else {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM customers WHERE 'Company' = '" . $q . "'";
};

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

When my main form submits with a "blank" value for COMPANY it works fine as the "str=all" is executed and returns to the browser all rows in the CUSTOMERS table. When I submit it with a value (that exists in the table) I get no rows back. I also get no errors back.

The syntax came from W3 and it works on their demo. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: step 1, never use W3Schools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're putting single quotes around your column name when single quotes are used to indicate the beginning and end of a string value. Use backticks instead. Change:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM customers WHERE 'Company' = '" . $q . "'";
```

to

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE `Company` = '" . $q . "'";
```

Note that this script is open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and that you should be [using prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).